# Does shellshock produce a comprehensive local privilege escalation vector?

Tags: shellshock, bash, privilege-escalation

If `setuid` scripts take arbitrary environment variables, apart from a few black-listed ones like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, from the caller, does this not mean that any `setuid` script running `#!/bin/bash` directly or indirectly is a vector for local escalation of privilege?

A good answer would be an explanation of why this is or is not the case.

For example, many (most?) unixalikes now do not honour `setuid` on shell scripts (though they did when this bug/backdoor was introduced). But binaries may call shell scripts indirectly, so unless they explicitly clear the environment first is this not still a problem?

Comment: Pretty good question: already containing the essential of risk analysis :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes!**

Binaries with a `setuid` bit and calling (directly or indirectly) `bash` through `execve`, `popen` or `system` are tools which may be used to activate the Shell Shock bug.

If these commands aren't taking care of clearing `*env` prior to run `bash` (or a shell script) then these binaries may be used to run any command (for example `bash`) with the privilege of `root`.

`popen` and `system` don't let the programmer the possibility to clean
`*env`.

Here is a first draft easy audit to **estimate** this risk:

```
find /  -perm +4000 \
    -exec /bin/zsh -c "ls -dluT {} ; nm -a {} | egrep '(popen|system|execve)' && strings {} | egrep '/bin/(sh|bash)'" \; 2>/dev/null
```

This isn't a **proof** of risk, since the `*env` might have been cleaned before the fork of the shell. The only way to be sure is to read the source code.

And here is the result on an actual version of an highly used Unix:

```
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  910848 Sep 29 16:31:18 2014 /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/ARDAgent
             U _popen
/bin/bash
```

(Here the last time used is not a proof of an attack but of my own previous "draft audit".)

Comment: Only as long as uid==euid and gid==egid.

Comment: No, bash doesn't import functions when setuid/setgid and if called by something that sets the ruid to the euid without sanitizing the environment, you're screwed anyway.

Comment: Isn't it a mistake to grep just for `bash` on systems where `/bin/sh` is also `bash`?

Comment: → MattBianco: right! I updated my *audit* of the poor :).

Answer (score 2):

When `bash` is invoked in setuid (or setgid) context, that is when the effective uid is different from the real uid, then `bash` drops the privileges (sets the effective uid back to the real uid).

Exception to that is when using the `-p` or `-o privileged` (the `SHELLOPTS` variable is ignored, so `privileged` in there as well) or when invoked as `sh`.

In that case though, functions are not imported from the environment (nor are things like `BASH_ENV`, `BASH_OPTS`, `SHELLOPTS` for the same obvious reasons).

If they were, you wouldn't need the shellshock vulnerability to exploit it. Just exporting an `echo` function (or anything called by the script including paths like `/bin/mount`) would do.

Some setuid commands may chose to set the ruid to the euid. If they do and don't sanitize the environment and call bash (or any other shell), then game's over, shellshock vulnerability or not.

The libc's dynamic linker takes care of removing some variables that affect the libc or linker (LD_PRELOAD, LOCPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH...), but it's up to the setuid application to clear the rest if they invoke other commands like a shell (or python, or any other command whose behaviour can be controlled with environment variables), the typical sane approach being to clear everything except a sanitized whitelist.

A typical example of such an application is `sudo`.

By default (with the `env_reset` option on), `sudo` clears the environment, sets a few (like `PATH`, `HOME`, `SUDO_USER`...) and whitelists a few after checking their content like `TERM` or `DISPLAY`. Part of that checking specially takes care of variables whose content starts with `()`.

If `env_reset` is off (disabled by the user/administrator), then `sudo` still blacklists a few variables that affect various shells or other common tools (like `PS4`, `BASH_ENV`...) and those whose content starts with `()`.

So shellshock cannot be exploited by doing:

```
DISPLAY='() {(:);}; ouch;}' sudo trusted-bash-script
```

Now, it's possible that there are setuid commands out there that set ruid and don't check for variables that start with `()` and invoke `bash` (possibly indirectly), but again no need for the shellshock bug to exploit those.

A possible exception to that is apache's `suexec`. As far as I know, `suexec` sanitizes the environment but only white-lists some variables based on their name, not their content. Without CVE-2014-6271, that wouldn't be a concern as those variables names  like `QUERYSTRING`, `HTTP_USER_AGENT` are not likely to match the name of a command, so it wasn't deemed necessary to block variables whose content starts with `"() {"`, but in practice that means it's exposed to CVE-2014-6271.

Comment: An example of a vulnerable command is `schroot`. `schroot` runs some setup scripts with root permissions (ruid==euid==0). The environment is mostly clean, but at least a user-settable session name is passed on an environment variable. This allows privilege escalation. There is another attack vector that requires sysadmin action, `user-modifiable-keys` allows additional custom variables (even `ld.preload`, which as an envvar gets turned into `LD_PRELOAD`), so sysadmins should use caution when copying schroot configurations from random tutorials.